# windows 8 on macbook locks after 2 mins despite high performance settings

Tags: windows-8, boot-camp, timeout

I am running my Macbook Prop as a Windows 8 machine using bootcamp and for some reason, when I leave the keyboard/mouse alone for 2 mins it locks the PC (i.e. goes to the lock screen).

I have (of course) checked the power settings and I can assure you that it is not set to these settings.

I did notice that when I added my work's Mail Account the computer asked me to accept some group policy settings, which I did, so I suspect that this is a group policy setting, but I cannot find it.

Can someone help?

P.S. I have searched these forums first, and this is different to the PC going to sleep once locked, this is locking while logged in after 2 mins.

Thanks.

Comment: If you can do a `GPResult -h gpresult.html` from a command prompt (cd to your desktop) then you can read if any policies have been set to override your power settings...

Comment: thanks for that, I just did that and it doesnt look like there are any group policy settings changed at all. So I might be wrong...

Comment: Goo through all your power settings again. Also, check your screensaver settings.

Comment: just went through all of them and nothing is set to the times that are occurring. I also have None selected on the screen saver. Is there something in the event viewer perhaps that I should look for?

Answer (score 0):

looks to be fixed, I had to reset my security policies, as found on this post

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ace4085a-b0ba-4a98-898d-cd92d9e88e13/windows-8-cannot-change-screensaver-timeout?forum=w8itprogeneral